# Laravel run command on docker container start, only once, without bash scripts

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-9

How could I do for example run a command every time the docker/laravel container is started?

Command example:

```php
Log::info('Service is runining');
```

This command is just an example, currently I have an `entrypoint.sh` that runs some commands when the docker container starts, but I want to pass this responsibility of running commands to Laravel.

How can I make the commands run only once?

Comment: In your Dockerfile, try: `CMD /path/to/laravel/artisan schedule:run` and running only once you can handle in Laravel itself

Comment: What do you want exactly to run once the container is up?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I want to run some migrations, run some AWS API calls, some Kubernetes API calls, things like that.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, why do you need to run that much on a local environment? You could run a shell script you have to write, but still... if it is a development environment, that's a lot to run once the docker is running. If it is production, check about linux running scripts you want on start up and then write a bash script doing whatever you want. Remember Laravel is a web app, not an OS